# Build Boost and Exempi on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, boost, boost-python

In order to install [Python XMP Toolkit](http://www.spacetelescope.org/static/projects/python-xmp-toolkit/docs/installation.html),
 I 
need to install Exempi on my Mac, but doing this is becoming a real nightmare...

After a lot of trouble, i finally made it with boost, and had the  fantastic

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!          
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
/usr/local/boost_1_44_0      
The following directory should be added to linker library paths:      
/usr/local/boost_1_44_0/stage/lib
```

Right now I'm trying to configure Exempi, with the command

```
./configure --with-boost=/usr/local/boost_1_44_0/
```

but it always get stuck on this:

```
checking for Boost headers version >= 1.33.0... /usr/local/boost_1_44_0/
checking for Boost's header version... 1_44
checking for the toolset name used by Boost for g++... gcc40
checking boost/test/unit_test.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/test/unit_test.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/test/unit_test.hpp... yes
checking for the Boost unit_test_framework library... no
configure: error: Could not find the flags to link with Boost unit_test_framework
```

I've been googlin for a couple of days, but I couldn't find anything useful...
Anyone had the same problem before? I would die for a helping hand... every hint is welcome!

**EDIT:**
I've made it with `port` and now it finally says `exempi @2.1.1_0 (active)`.
The problem is that when I try to load the XMP toolkit, it doesn't find exempi, and raises an error, as reported on the installation guide:

> in case you haven’t installed Exempi you will get an `ExempiLoadError` exception once you try to load libxmp.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you installed Boost manually, given that it's in /usr/local. I was able to install both Boost and Exempi through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

Comment: Yes, I had to install it manually. Sadly, is almost impossible for me to use MacPorts, because I'm living on an island with an unstable 400k shared internet connection...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't build the boost test library when you built boost. You need to add `--with-test` to your `bjam` invokation:

`./bjam --with-test`